# Thymeleaf String Concatenation

Tags: thymeleaf

Thymeleaf String concatenation not work

data-th-text=${employee.empFirstName} +' '+ ${employee.empLastName}

could anyone explain reason for this.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You have two options (span is just a example-element):

1.)

```
<span th:text="${employee.empFirstName + ' ' + employee.empLastName}"></span>
```

2.) using "|...|"

```
<span th:text="|${employee.empFirstName} ${employee.empLastName}|"></span>
```

You are using data-th-text (writting html5 custom attributes). You can use the same syntax here. Have a look at the single- and double-quotes, vertical lines and ${...} blocks.